# If $A$ is the ring of continuous functions on a genus $g$ surface, can the genus of $X$ be seen by simple algebra in $A$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, surfaces

I was describing to a friend the result that a compact Hausdorff space is determined up to homeomorphism up to by its ring of continuous functions, and he asked how one could see the genus of a surface algebraically. I think it's a good question, and I don't know the answer.

Two parts to this question:

1. Suppose it is known that $A$ is the ring of continuous functions of a closed surface $X$ (topological manifold, real 2-dimensional) of genus $g$. Where in the algebraic structure of $A$ is the genus of $X$? (There are comments from other users about $K$-theory below... I want to emphasize that I am dreaming of a simple algebraic characterization, analogous to the relationship between idempotents and connected components.)
2. Does the answer to 1 say something interesting for more general classes of rings (ex, those that are rings of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space, or more general rings...)

Any ideas? (Analogous to the idempotents / connected components dictionary.)

Here are some thoughts of my own:

1. Picking a smooth structure on $X$ amounts to passing to some subring of differentiable functions. In this setting, results about the existence of vector fields with zeros of prescribed index could be interpreted as the existence of derivations with some prescribed zeros (by choosing some arbitrary Riemannian metric and translating the results about vector fields) - though its not clear how to interpret the index of the zero algebraically, or how to describe these subrings.
2. Consider all ring homomorphisms to $C(X) \to C(S^1)$ up the homotopy relation induced by factoring through $C(S^1 \times I)$ in the right way. This crudely recaptures the fundamental group, but I don't see how to turn it into an algebraic condition.
3. Vector bundles are the same as finite projective modules via Swan's theorem - so certain sections of the vector bundle are elements of the corresponding module? Maybe one could get at the Poincare-Hopf computation of the genus that way, but again I don't see how to compute the index. (Also as far as I know, one still needs a smooth structure to use Poincare-Hopf.)

I would be happy to just be able to distinguish $S^2$ and $T^2$ via their ring of continuous functions.

Comment: You may be interested in [Morse Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I know a little bit of Morse Theory, but I'm really looking for an algebraic characterization through the ring $A$, not an analytic one given by studying some individual (smooth) function. (Unless this is what you mean, in which case please say more.)

Comment: K-theory is no good here. You can't tell oriented surfaces apart with their (topological) complex K-theory rings.

Comment: I *think* but don't quite remember that you can tell them apart with $K_1$ (instead of $K_0$, which is what I was thinking about above), which should be accessible from the $C^*$-algebra of continuous functions via operator K-theory.

Comment: @MikeMiller I'm completely ignorant of $K$-theory, so I don't see the connection. However, I think that accessing the full structure $C^*$ algebra structure (in particular, the norm) requires passing back to topological space first. I really am dreaming of something inherently algebraic, like the description of $H_0$ in terms of idempotents.

Comment: The norm is just the supremum of the functions - that's a set-level construct. But I see your point (you don't care about the actual functions, just the algebra of them).

Comment: @MikeMiller I guess one can define the norm as $sup_{m \in mSpecA} f(m)$, where $f(m)$ is the equivalence class mod $m$ for $m$ going over all maximal ideals. The function can be recovered from the algebra in this way, but it doesn't feel very algebraic.

Comment: The Grothendieck group construction is purely algebraic as far as I know, so the C*-algebra doesn't need to 'know' which space it came from. This makes sense especially when you extend the theory to non-commutative spaces which can't be realised as function rings on a topological space. So I think $K$ theory is enough in this instance, and directly corresponds to the cohomology of the surfaces being studied.

Comment: @DanRust Ok, thanks. Can you suggest a reference?

Comment: There is something called "formal geometry" that I *think* could be of interest to you, but I'm not nearly enough of an expert to give a precise answer. Nice question, BTW. (Maybe this question would fare better on MO -- perhaps you can ask a moderator to migrate it.)

Comment: Given the ring $A$, one recovers the space $X$ as the MaxSpec of $A$, and then you can compute the genus (or any other topological invariant) of $X$ any way you like --- for example, via Cech cohomology.  The two steps --- going from $A$ to $X$ and going from $X$ to its genus --- are easily described, so it's easy to describe the composition.  "Easily described" is not the same thing as "transparent", but I don't see a reason to expect transparency.

Comment: Real line bundles on $X$ are classified by $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, so assuming you mean continuous real-valued functions, the number of isomorphism classes of rank $1$ projective modules over $A$ is $4^g$.

Comment: And if you mean complex functions you can pass to real functions by looking at the elements with real spectrum.

Comment: @Steven: one major reason to expect transparency is that the K-theory of $X$ can be defined directly from $A$, without passing to the MaxSpec. So it's not completely unreasonable to expect that there are interesting things you can say without passing to MaxSpec. Similarly we can look at the cyclic or Hochschild homology.

Answer (score 15):

I'll assume we're talking about complex functions; if real, tensor with $\mathbb{C}$. Now pass to the group of units. With the topology given by spectral radius (this is an algebraic description of the C-* topology), the group of connected components of the group of units is $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ which of course knows the genus.

If you really like idempotents then you should try learning about K-theory. There's a very concrete and elementary way to define $K^0$ in terms of idempotents in the matrix algebras $M_n(A)$. You don't need the C*-structure of $A$. But on the other hand $K^0$ doesn't know the genus of a surface. $K^1$ does but it's a bit trickier to define, I think.

**Edit:** $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ can be isolated a bit more algebraically too. To extract $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ from the group of units it suffices to isolate the connected component of the identity. The elements in this connected component can be distinguished by the fact that they are divisible.

**Edit #2:** So, purely for the sake of distinguishing $S^2$ and $T^2$, you can say the following: on $S^2$, every unit has a square root, but not on $T^2$.

Comment: @Arul: take the equivalence relation generated by the relation "two units are connected by a straight line consisting of units." I think this is the same as the same-component relation but I haven't thought about it in detail.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, you are right. Obviously, if two units are connected by a line of units, they induce the same map $H_1(X) \to H_1(\mathbb{C}^{\ast})$. Conversely, if $u$ and $v$ are maps $X \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ inducing the same map on homology, then $u v^{-1}$ has a continuous logarithm $w$, and then $v \exp(a w)$ is a continuous path from one to the other, for $a \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @David: but not a straight line, right? Although maybe you're saying that path can easily be approximated by straight lines? (Which is the sort of argument I had in mind.) I wanted to avoid mentioning exponentials to keep things as algebraic as possible: talking about straight lines only requires a real vector space structure.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am confused by what you mean by "straight line". You mean literally straight in the vector space. That sounds plausible but I need to think a bit about whether it is actually true.

Comment: Choose $N$ large enough that $|w|/N < \pi$. Then $\exp(w/N)$ is disjoint from the negative real line, so $a \exp(w/N) + (1-a)$ is a unit for all $a \in [0,1]$. Thus $a v \exp((k+1) w/N) + (1-a) v \exp(k w/N)$ is a unit for all such $a$, and we can take a piecewise linear path through the points $v \exp(k w/N)$ for $0 \leq k \leq N$.

Comment: Nice. I figured the argument would need to use compactness, which is used here to conclude that $w$ is bounded and so $|w|$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will hopefully have a good excuse to some $K$ theory soon. I like the spirit of your second edit. Unfortunately, once we have a $\pi_1$ surjective map to $S^1$ from our surface I don't see how to get more information out of maps to $\mathbb{C}^*$ (in order to distinguish higher genus surfaces). Maybe a Lie group $G$ with higher rank $\pi_1$ and enough "algebraic" covers would provide access to finitely more information $\pi_1(S)$ via the group theory of $C(S,G)$? Or is the situation of the covers of $\mathbb{C}^*$ special? (In terms of their algebraic nature.)

Comment: I guess the natural thing to do is to look at maps to $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$.

Comment: @Area: I don't really understand your question; it seems to be at least two different questions at once, which seem worth separating. First, it sounds like you're worried that I haven't distinguished higher genus surfaces, but I have: this is covered in Edit #1. Second, there are lots of interesting things to say about, say, principal $G$-bundles and $G$-local systems on a surface but it's not obvious that this information is easily accessible starting from the ring of functions (although there are things to say here).

Comment: I just meant that the second edit doesn't distinguish between higher genus  surfaces, because there are going to be maps from higher genus surfaces into $\mathbb{C}^*$ that don't lift via the cover $z \to z^2$ (no square root). The thought was that more could be seen from the continuous maps into the Lie group $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$, by looking at covers like $(z_0, \ldots, z_n) \to (z_0^2, \ldots, z_n^2)$. But this doesn't seem to quite work, or at least the counting roots statement is more complicated. About your $K$-theory remarks: I don't know why the group of connected components is $H^1$.

Comment: @Area: the group of connected components of the group of units is the group of homotopy classes of maps $X \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. The latter space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, so equivalently we're talking about the group of homotopy classes of maps $X \to S^1$. And this is of course precisely $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: The spectral radius topology induces the same topology on the group of units as the sup norm topology on $C(X,\mathbb{C}^*)$? So the connected components of the identity are those maps homotopic to a point. Is the group structure on the $[X,S^1]_+$ that induced from $S^1$? Some $f: X \to S^1$ induces a $\mathbb{Z} \to H^1(X)$, and $H^1(f) = 0$ implies $\pi_1(f) = 0$, so that via the contractible cover $f \cong 0$. $H^1(mult)(1) = (1,1)$ implies this is a homomorphism. It is not clear to me that this is a surjection in general. (For closed surfaces I see a cell structure that maybe shows it.)

Comment: Is surjectivity easy? Where can I find a reference for this last fact?

Comment: @Area: on $C(X, \mathbb{C})$ the spectral radius and sup norm coincide. The group structure is induced from that of $S^1$. What I have in mind in general is that cohomology is represented by Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, and $S^1$ is the Eilenberg-MacLane space $B \mathbb{Z}$. In the particular case of $S^1$ you can also argue using the exponential sheaf sequence, as follows. There is a short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to 0$ of sheaves on $X$ (here each object stands for the sheaf of continuous functions into that object), which induces a long...

Comment: ...exact sequence in cohomology part of which goes $\dots \to H^0(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^0(X, \mathbb{C}^{\times}) \to H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to 0$. This shows that $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ (once you believe that sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ agrees with singular cohomology; let me assume $X$ is a reasonable space so this is true) is the quotient of the group of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ by the subgroup of exponentials of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$; this turns out to be the connected component of the identity (exercise).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! As for your exercise, sending $\lambda \to 0$ in $e^{\lambda f(z)}$ provides a nullhomotopy for exponentials, and conversely if $f(z)$ is in the connected component of the identity, then it induces trivial maps on $\pi_1$ and hence lifts to the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^*$, i.e. is an exponent.

Comment: What is unclear to me is why $H^1 (X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1 (X, \mathbb{C})$ is the zero map... $\mathbb{C}$ is divisible group, so an injective object in the category of abelian groups. Does it follow that the sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ is an injective object in the category of sheaves of abelian groups on $X$ (I'm concerned that non-uniqueness of the extension is an obstruction to gluing an extension) so it has no higher cohomology?

Comment: @Area: the sheaf of continuous functions to $\mathbb{C}$ is fine, so for reasonable $X$ that means it's acyclic (that is, all higher cohomology vanishes). Your argument doesn't seem to have enough resolution to distinguish between the sheaf of continuous functions and the sheaf of holomorphic functions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, that is a good point. Does sheaf of holomorphic functions on a projective Riemann surface have the same betti numbers as the Cech cohomology of the corresponding algebraic curve? I think I have heard something like this. So there is no good reason to suspect that the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ is injective.

Comment: @Area: no, but they're related. For the correct statement look up the Hodge decomposition. On a compact Riemann surface $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \cong \mathbb{C}^g$ (not $2g$), and all higher cohomology vanishes.

Answer (score 10):

The torus has two functions $f$ and $g$ which are (1) relatively prime, (2) each have two square roots, and (3) whose product has $4$ square roots. For instance take two functions which vanish on disjoint loops which are not null-homologous. There sphere does not have two such functions because (1) implies that $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ are disjoint and (2) implies that the complement of $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ are connected, and (3) implies that the complement of $V(fg)$ is not connected. These conditions are impossible to all satisfy at once on the sphere.

Comment: I think a similar technique should work for surfaces in general, the idea being to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to convert a question about the dimension of $H^1$ into a question about the dimension of some $H^0$'s which counts connected components, which can in turn be detected by numbers of square roots.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant and simple idea. (I guess you are thinking of the real valued functions here, at least that is what I am visualizing.)